# how to save 32bit binary number in keil

Tags: assembly

I have 1800 32-bit binary numbers, and I have to load these numbers to register.

the numbers are represented by floating point expression. I have to make data area

that saves 1800 floating numbers, 
but if I use

DCD 11000010011111111000000000000000

error occurs.

How can I save 32-bit binary numbers in keil?

Comment: keil is not an architecture or platform. The keil IDE supports various architectures from 8-bit 8051 to 32-bit ARM. You must specify what architecture you're targeting

Comment: Read the manual whether it accepts binary numbers and if so, what format. Otherwise, convert to decimal or hex yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from what the Keil manual says about [numeric literals](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731177483.htm), it seems that the syntax for using binary literals is:

> `DCD 2_11000010011111111000000000000000`

So you may want to try that instead.

Comment: But I have 1800 data that don't have 2_ at start, Is there any method to read 32-bit numbers binary automatically?

Comment: @CHANHOJUNG: I wouldn't know; I don't know anything about Keil. If it were me, though, I'd probably just write a simple Python script to do the conversion.

Comment: @CHANHOJUNG you have 1800 strings in binary format? If you would have binary data, you would need just to load them into memory. And you can translate data outside of keil and link them together with code during linking, or even load dynamically from code